# Introduction to covariance matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, statistics

I am starting to learn about quantum information theory, particularly that with continuous variables.

It seems that lots of problems rely on calculating the covariance matrix of your quantum state.

I have seen how the covariance matrix is defined in terms of variances of quadrature operators, but I am struggling to follow how one would then construct a [covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) for an actual quantum state.

Could someone please recommend a good book or paper which will walk me through this?

Comment: Are you talking about bosons or fermions?  And also beyond that, it would not hurt if you could make your question more specific (what do you need, what kind of systems do you want to study, what do you know).

Comment: Thinking about bosons, in particular gaussian states of light which I know can be completely described by their covariance matrix.

I'm looking mainly for a resource which will explain how the covariance matrix is constructed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A detailed introduction into bosonic Gaussian states can be e.g. found in Appendix A of Geza Giedke's PhD thesis, https://people.phys.ethz.ch/~giedke/Thesis/DissRV2.pdf.

Comment: I have the same question as the OP.  The link you provided does not work.